# Dotted lines with border around the dots?

Tags: tikz-styles

When we are working with lines, it is possible to change the border color of a line using the parameter "double". Another option is to draw a thicker line in the background and use it as border.

But the none of the options seems to work with dotted lines. Is it possible to create a line with several dots that have a border around them?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with two dotted lines: `densely dotted` (like background) and `losely dotted` options ...

Comment: Or maybe two dotted lines with `very thick` (like background) and (for second line) `thin`, `very thin` or without options ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work because the size of the dots were determined by the line width, so the very thick didn't have any effect :(.

If I increase the line width the dots does not fall in the same spot :(.

Comment: You should explicitly defined length of line segments and space between them.

Comment: Yes, but how to fit one exactly over the other if the size of the dots are different?

Comment: Define equal dots, see answer or provide MWE that I can see, what is your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Your requirements are not very clear... Here is a proposition:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  dotted bordered/.style={
    decorate,decoration={markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 6pt with {
        \draw[line width=.3pt,#1,fill=none] circle(2pt);
        \fill[#1,draw=none] circle(1pt);
      }
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[dotted bordered={fill=violet,draw=green}]
  (0,0) -- (3,1) -- (1,3) to[out=180,in=90] (0,1);

  \draw[dotted bordered=red] (1.5,1.5) circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```